# Nav items on header change based on section

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, nav

On my website I've got a sticky header with several different nav items on it that when clicked will scroll down to find that section on the page.  I was wondering how one would go about setting it up so the nav items change colour when the view is on the section it corresponds to.  In other words, if the viewer is on section 'x', 'x' on the nav bar will change color.

Update: heres the code for the nav bar im using

```
<div class = 'nav-container'>
    <nav>
        <div id = 'nav-items-container'>
            <ul class='nav-items'>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#what'>what</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#how'>how</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#why'>why</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#who'>who</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#where'>where</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

some css

```
.nav-container{
   background-color:black;
   height:50px;
   width:410px;
   font-size: 120%;
   position:absolute;
}



a:link{
    color:white;
}

a:visited{
    color:#58ACFA;
}
#nav-items-container ul li{
    display:inline;
}

#nav-items-container ul li a{
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav-items-container ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:15px;
}
```

Comment: Including code you have used to try and solve the problem will increase the likelihood of a response.

Comment: include your css as well

Comment: Do you want nav item to change when clicked on?  Or when the page is scrolled to the part of the page that is relevant to the nav item?

Comment: the latter.  id like it to change based on the section

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery you can do something like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var sections = [],
            anchors = $('#nav-items-container a[href^="#"]'),  // anchor links with hash tags
            docHeight = $(document).height(),
            currentOffset,
            setNavActive;

        // handler to update the class  
        setNavActive = function(hash){
            anchors.removeClass('current-section');
            anchors.filter('a[href="' + hash + '"]').addClass('current-section');
        };
        
        // building our hash/start/end position map 
        $.each(anchors, function(i, item) {
            currentOffset = $(item.hash).offset().top;
            if (i > 0) {
                sections[i-1].end = currentOffset;
            }
            
            sections[i] = { 
                            hash: item.hash, 
                            start: (i == 0 ? 0 : currentOffset),
                            end: docHeight
                          };
        });
        
        // on scroll event, check which map fits, 
        // find the hash and set the class          
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            currentOffset = $(document).scrollTop();
            for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
                if (sections[i].start <= currentOffset && sections[i].end > currentOffset) {
                    setNavActive(sections[i].hash);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I added a new style but you can make it nested or whatever:

```
.current-section {background:pink; }
```

### jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/fstreamz/krb6Q/3/

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here to give the best answer.  I can give one that works though.

Chang your headers to look like this:

```
<li class='nav-item' id = "nav_what"><a href='#what'>what</a></li>
<li class='nav-item' id = "nav_how"><a href='#how'>how</a></li>
<li class='nav-item' id = "nav_why"><a href='#why'>why</a></li>
<li class='nav-item' id = "nav_who"><a href='#who'>who</a></li>
<li class='nav-item' id = "nav_where"><a href='#where'>where</a></li>
```

then in the body of each page put

```
<script>
document.getElementById('nav_what').style.backgroundColor = "gray";
</script>
```

You would have to switch it out on each page with the correct id.  Its more traditionally done manually with inline styles if the header is not loaded externally.

Comment: the issue here is that the entire site is on one page.  The goal was to have the nav item change when looking at that section on the one page

Answer (score 0):

Add another `CSS` declaration as below and apply `active` style to the current page.

```
#nav-items-container ul li.active a {
    color:red;
}
```

Apply the above style like this...

```
<li class='nav-item active'><a href='#what'>what</a></li>
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/KGMCx/1/)